# Pull HTML content from remote website and display on page

Tags: php, jquery, dom, curl, jquery-load

Been working on this for a little while now and am stumped. I am attempting to pull the content from within a specific div on a remote website page and then insert that html into a div on my own website. I know that you cannot solely use jQuery's .ajax, .load, or .get methods for this type of operation.

Here's the remote page's HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <table class="table">
                ...table #1 content...
                ...More table content...
            </table>
            <table class="table">
                ...table #2 content...
            </table>
            <table class="table">
                ...table #3 content...
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Goal:**
I am attempting to fetch the html from the remote page's first table. So, on my website, I would like the following html to be fetched and placed in a div of id="fetched-html":

```
<table class="table">
    ...table #1 content...
    ...More table content...
</table>
```

Here's where I'm at with my PHP function thus far:

```
<?php
function pullRaspi_SDImageTable() {
    $url = "http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Create new PHP DOM document
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    // Load html from curl request into document model
    $DOM->loadHTML($output);

    // Get 1st table
    $output = $DOM->firstChild->getElementsByTagName('table');

    return $output;
}
?>
```

The final result should look like this on my local website page:

```
<div id="fetched-html">
    <table class="table">
        ...table #1 content...
        ...More table content...
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's another PHP function possibility?

```
<?php
function pullRaspPi_SDImageTable() {
    // Url to fetch
    $url = "http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen("raspberrypi_sdimagetable.txt", "w");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

    // Write html source to variable
    $rasp_sdimagetable = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close curl request
    curl_close($ch);

    return $rasp_sdimagetable;
}

// Then in the head of the html, add this jQuery:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#fetched-html").load("<?php pullRaspPi_SDImageTable(); ?> table.table:first");
</script>
```

Problem is, neither function works. :( Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting a fragment of HTML from a website is a breeze with [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) you can then do something like:

```
function pullRaspi_SDImageTable() {
    $filename = '/tmp/downloads.html';  /// Where you want to cache the result
    $expiry = 600;  // 10 minutes
    $output = '';

    if (!file_exists($filename) ||  time() - $expiry > filemtime($filename)) {
        // There is no cache, so fetch the results from remote server
        require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads');
        foreach($html->find('div.entry-content table.table') as $elem) {
                $output .= (string)$elem;
        }

        // Store the cache
        file_put_contents($filename, $output);
    } else {
        // Pull the content from the cahce
        $output = file_get_contents($filename);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Which will give you the `table.table` HTML

Comment: Yea, thanks for the solution, but how does simplehtmldom work? Is this a PHP extension? Won't using a method/function to parse html non-standard to PHP be slower and put more strain on the server? That's why I tried going the cURL route since I know that is built into PHP. Any more info on simplehtmldom would be appreciated!

Comment: There is, of course, a little more overhead than using DomDocument since this is a userland class, but it is well written and used by many projects.  In this case, it would not be much slower. The time it takes to fetch the document from a remote server (via curl or anything else) is the real burden. So I would implement a simple file cache to cache the result of the output for 10 minutes.  This would give you the best performance when your site is being hit multiple times since subsequent requests are dumped from the cache.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how to implement a simple file cache and cache the result using either simplehtmldom or DomDocument model? Sorry, I'm very much a PHP beginner. Something like this maybe? [http://davidwalsh.name/php-cache-function](http://davidwalsh.name/php-cache-function)

Comment: Nice @itsmejodie!! Thanks so much! A couple more quick questions... how could I go about only parsing/selecting the first table in the fetched html? Currently, I believe all tables in <div class="entry-content"> are being parsed and displayed, correct? Also, simplehtmldom is required once before the function. Does this put a lot of strain on the server? Everytime someone hits the page and the function run, I guess is this file reloaded in? Or, is it loaded into memory the first time the function runs. Because the PHP script is local, is the speed loss/strain negligible?

Comment: Put the `require_once()` inside the cache check and it will only happen once. It's only a single 15KB class so I doubt even when it is loaded it will have much effect on your performance. Correct that each table (with class table) is being included. If you only want the first table, then instead of the `foreach` just do `$elem = $html->find('div.entry-content')->find('table.table'); $output .= (string)$elem;`

Answer (score -1):

> you cannot solely use jQuery's .ajax, .load, or .get methods for this
>   type of operation

Yes, you can BUT the remote website must give you authorization for that.. just inserting an iframe and using the normal DOM functions you could IF THERE IS NOT cross domain restrictions.

You can get a FULL page only with php (using the common functions include, require, etc and passing the website URL but, same case, you need to be authorized..