# How to Display a PHP Code on Certain URL of a Website

Tags: php

I want to display a PHP code On a Certain URL, to trigger few codes of CSS on that page.

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
<?php 
if($url == 'test.com/local/memebership') 
{
echo $this->__('<style>label[for=product_id---1] {display: none;}</style>');
}
    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: where do you get `$url` from?

Comment: @bwoebi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908521/pull-html-content-from-remote-website-and-display-on-page

Comment: You want to display `<style>label[for=product_id---1] {display: none;}</style>` in page right?

Comment: @sal00m Yes on a specific url

Comment: And the problem is with url detection or displaying the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/local/memebership') {
    // Your code goes here. 
    echo '<style>label[for=product_id---1] {display: none;}</style>';

    // If you need to echo content from any file
    // passthru('/path/to/file.css'); 

    // Exit right after echoing
    die(); 
}
```

Also if it is including code on a page with tag `<link>` you need to add header with content-type like follows:

```
header ('Content-Type: text/css');
```

In this case you need to change your code and remove tags `<style>`

Comment: Awesome man! Worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you must validate the current URI.

```
if (preg_match("/^(\/)?local\/membership/i", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) // or $url
{ 
    echo "We are somewhere below local/membership"; 
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the code? Did you copy/paste or did you adjust it to fit your environment? Try removing `^(\/)?` from the expression to find any url with the local/membership.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the array, $_SERVER

To get the requested page, use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

So your script could be like

```
<?php
$url = '/local/memebership';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $url)
{
  echo 'something';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the code you can use something like this:

```
function displayCode($str)
{
 return "<pre>".htmlentities($str)."</pre>"; //use <code> if needed
}
```

To detect the server use $_SERVER @Nathan and @Daniel gives you an example to detect one URL, if you wnat to detect the server, use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`