# jquery .load with script in it

Tags: jquery

I need load piece of content into my div, I need execute the script I have in remote div, for example I have

```
<div id="thisIsRemoteContent">
<script src="blabla.js"></script>
</div>
```

in the remote-content.html

Now I need load it with script to my page

```
$('.mydiv').load("remote-content.html #thisIsRemoteContent");
```

In jquery API documentation was written that if I load piece of contet, then the script will not be executed.

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed.

However, how can I load it with script?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908521/pull-html-content-from-remote-website-and-display-on-page may this helps

Answer (score 1):

cant you do 2 calls?

```
    $('.mydiv').load("remote-content.html");
    $.getScript('blabla.js');
```

you can manipulate with the script name so the remote content will know what its name and then put it in some attribute inside the `remote-content.html` like:

```
<div>my remote content</div>
<span scriptname="blabla.js"></span>
```

so then:

```
    $('.mydiv').load("remote-content.html");
    $.getScript($('span[scriptname]').attr('scriptname'));
```

Comment: thank you for answer, I can't do anything with script, it is comming from admin panel, user is just putting the script like this

'<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=GkmrD6Ltyaz5d3OM4veFHV_IBKH3_rqT&width=320&height=319"></script>'

I can manipulate only with its parent-wrapper

Comment: i dont know then. its a big issue all the XSS protections makes the work much harder for us ;)